# Como selecionar determinada linha do listView java

Tags: java, android

Como eu faço para pegar o id da linha de um listView?
A ideia é a seguinte: antes de pegar a linha selecionada, eu vou trabalhar com todas as linhas estou tentando.

```
aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();        

for(int i=0;i<countries.length;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
    hm.put("txt", getString(countries[i]));

    aList.add(hm);        
}

String[] from = { "txt" };


int[] to = { R.id.txt};        


SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);       

        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

...

```
OnItemClickListener listener = new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, final int arg2, long arg3) {



                for(int i=0;i< arg0.getCount();i++){

                não sei fazer o setText(); em todos os 'R.id.txt'...    

            }
```

Se alguém tiver uma ideia de como fazer eu agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro verifique sua lógica do evento, você está usando um evento de selecionar um item da lista, não entendi porque mudar o resto dos itens.

Antes de alterar o item da lista preciso saber o que tipo de itens ela possui, ou você criou uma lista simples com array de String, ou então você pode ter carregado ela com objetos( e ter personalizado os itens do ListView).

**EXEMPLO COM STRINGS:**

Declare um ArrayList de strings e um ArrayAdapter globais na classe

```
ArrayList<String> arrayItens;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

//chame esse método no inicio da atividade, para carregar a lista.
private void carregaLista(){
        arrayItens = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayItens.add("um");
        arrayItens.add("dois");
        arrayItens.add("tres");
        //Cria um adapter e o referencia com o arrayItens
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayItens);
        //seta sua ListView com o adapter que está contendo seu array
        lvLista.setAdapter(adapter);
        //uma vez setado o adapter do seu ListView, 
        //você não precisa mais trabalhar diretamente com o ListView para manipular seus dados, 
        //você trabalha diretamente na fonte de dados que seria o arrayItens e o adapter. 
    }
```

No evento do OnItemClickListener altere as linhas seguintes.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
        //modifica a string na posicao exata do arrayList que esta referenciado pelo adapter
        arrayItens.set(position, "esse numero foi selecionado"); //esse texto vai aparecer na tela no lugar do numero.
        //com o arrayList modificado o adapter manda atualizar todas suas referencias com algum componente gráfico que no caso é o ListView.
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //atualiza o ListView
}
```

Caso precisar fazer a modificação em todos os itens, você pode fazer um **for** no arrayItens. e depois do **for** não esqueça de chamar o método notifyDataSetChanged (chame esse método fora do laço for) para atualizar o listview na tela.

Comment: Bom, desde já agradeço a sua resposta @Juarez. Esqueci de citar que estou usando um layout na listview que tem um TextView com id 'txt' e é nele que eu quero setar o texto.

Comment: Presumo então que você criou uma classe de ItemListView e uma classe Adapter que extende de BaseAdapter, é isso? mas mesmo assim será quase a mesma lógica desse exemplo que fiz

Comment: se sim, insira o código dessas classes na pergunta.

Comment: Ok! pergunta reformulada.